# PHP HTML mail rendering tags in outlook

Tags: php, html-email

I've used this example on the PHP site to send an HTML email, but when I recieve a mail sent by the script it renders the tags in the client (Outlook)

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Birthday Reminders for August</title> 
</head>
<body>
<p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
</tr>
 </table>
</body>
 </html>
 ';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

My client is set up to recieve HTML mail - so I'm not sure what's going on. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to fix your existing script but for sending HTML E-Mails, I always recommend using a ready-made class like [**PHPMailer**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/): It provides safe and clean handling of multi-part mails, multiple recipients, and even file attachments.

Comment: I second this answer. Mailing is so complex that using an existing class is always a good idea. Personally I've used Zend_Mail lately, but it's up to you to find what you like best.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. If Outlook has a feature to see the original source code of a message, you should inspect it carefully and see if there's something wrong.

Sometimes the e-mail client would ignore some headers if you happen to mix Windows and Unix style line feeds.

Also:

- Don't add the **To** header explicitly. PHP will do it for you.
- Remove the leading carriage returns in $headers.