# My Emails sent through PHP shows as tags only for a few recipients (sending a few hundred)

Tags: html-email, php

Im sending out an order conformation for recipients via the simple mail function built into PHP, and this works fine. It's a "nice" email set up in tables and a few styles with the details in it

However a few of the recipients just see html tags, and of course can't understand anything..

If i get one, it shows perfectly in thunderbird, hotmail, gmail..

The html is perfect, not missing any end tags, and i send some headers also as i have read i should. this is my mail send function:

```
$body = "some html tags, set up in a table" ;
$sendto = "The recipients email here" ;
$subject = "subject here" ;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$headers .= "To: theemailhere <theemailhere>\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <thefromemailhere>' . "\r\n";
mail($sendto, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Is this an error from my side, or has the recipient chosen not to receive html emails? I mean is this still possible in 2012 and do people disable this??

And if so, what could be a good workaround to do this. I mean i would like to avoid using plain text.

Comment: Yes people do disable it. I disable it.  If you're going to send HTML, it is advisable to send a multipart/mime message containing a plain text part and an html part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP HTML mail rendering tags in outlook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043490/php-html-mail-rendering-tags-in-outlook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are **really** email clients which do not allow HTML emails. I guess older Outlooks are one of these, too, but not sure.

So, anyway, it is not your fault, it is the user's. See Source 1 and Source 2.

And you can never be sure what does the user's mail program accept. Only plaintext is surely accepted. Quoting Source 2:

> "The best you can do is anticipate how each of the major clients will
>   break your design, and then try to control how it breaks, so that it’s
>   still readable by most of your recipients."

It can be solved only with multipart messages, but then some people will get plaintext. See Source 3 for some details on the issue and Source 4 for solutions.

Some documents on this: [Source 1](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails), [Source 2](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/creating-html-emails/), [Source 3](http://www.clickz.com/clickz/column/1710825/the-myth-multipart), [Source 4](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/php/html-plain-text-mail/)

Comment: Thanks this cleared it up a bit.. Would you recommend multipart messages then?
I can see that if i do this, then some of those who can read html will accidentally get the plain text version instead.

Comment: Yes and no. No in case that you think it's good if you force those few people to change email type in their own personal settings or read the tags - so if this signup has a login page. If you think that users shouldn't be asked to set, then use multipart, it is better than tags.

Comment: Dang it... Now it seems that some of those who just receives tags actually can read html messages sent by others.
Any suggestions why this could be? :(

Answer (score 0):

I've been using `Zend_Mail` recently (from ZF), which has the option to set a plain text message, and then a HTML message which overrides it where HTML is available. I'm unsure of how this is implemented in the message (headers/etc.) but this could be an answer to your problems.