# HTML Mail with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

Currently i am using simple mail function to send mail to our customer. But some customer complaints that html code appear in their mail client and attachement show as text in base64 code.

I need the good html mailer with php, couple of year back i used one good mailer but now i forget their name.

Please help me to get a good mailer with PHP, so that our customer will not compalin.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

try this , it is good mailer library

[Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Swiftmailer which maxjackie already mentioned or try to send multipart messages. If you wish to use that, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249829/my-emails-sent-through-php-shows-as-tags-only-for-a-few-recipients-sending-a-fe/9249847) question.